# How to check which svn revision did I add the specific file to Xcode

Tags: xcode, svn

I've two targets in the Xcode project. Normally when I add a new file, it would be added to both targets.

But I find my mistake today that one file was added only to one target, which leads to a bug. And I want to find out in which svn revision I added this file. Or in which revision I did something stupid to remove the file from one target?

Thanks to @michael,

**Use** `svn log PATH_TO_FILE` **to check the very first revision of this file and when you modified it.**

**What if I want to know when I deselect the file from one target?**

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to see where the file was added to subversion is on the command line, where you can type in "`svn log PATH_TO_FILE`".  And that will list out the log of all the commits that changed this file, back to when it was added.

Now, within Xcode, if you open that same file and click on the "Version Editor" for the file (which you can do by clicking on the below icon):

[image]

the bottom of both files being "diffed" is a *pop up* list of the revision history.

For me it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Yes that svn command works. But what I can see is the comment that people write when they commit. I can only know the revision number. Any way that answers half the question. Thank you.

Comment: Did I not understand your question?  In my example up there, there's four revision numbers (starting with the file being introduced in revision 382).  And "`svn log`" shows the same info.

Comment: what I am trying to describe is like this: you select an .m file in xcode, look at the right side, the property panel, deselect one target in "Target Membership". At this moment, you are not modifying that .m file. So the svn won't log this deselect operation on the .m file. I want to find when I did this kind of operations.